# Passar um JSON da view para a rota

Tags: php, javascript, json, laravel

Estou tentando enviar um `JSON` da `view` para uma rota, mas não estou conseguindo. Infelizmente sei pouco sobre `JSON`, `ajax`, `GET` e `POST`.

Na view, o json:

```
var json = {
  "numeroMesa": numeroMesa,
  "itens": itens 
};
```

Lembrando que a variável `numeroMesa` é uma variável global no `javascript` e `itens` é um array com alguns números.

Logo em seguida, tenho:

```
$.get('addPedido/' + json, function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

E na rota, tenho:

```
Route::get('/addPedido/{json}', function($json) {
  $json = JSON_decode($json);
  return $json;
});
```

Quando envio, o alert não mostra nada. Estou utilizando o *framework* `laravel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é a melhor maneira, ou posso dizer ainda que está errado.

Você está concatenando um objeto javascript com uma string (na url).

```
  var json = {
      "numeroMesa": numeroMesa,
      "itens": itens 
  };

$.get('addPedido/' + json)
```

Por sua vez O Laravel,  espera que você passe um outro segmento (a palavra da url entre barras `/`) quando você utiliza `{json}`.

Uma string json passada na url ficaria ruim e poderia causar erros. Sem contar que você não converteu o objeto do javascript para json através de `JSON.stringify`.

A abordagem correta seria usar os parâmetros da `url` na requisição ajax. Assim:

```
$.get('addPedido/', json, function () { /**...**/ })
```

Assim, você poderia, pela rota do `Laravel`, usar o método `Input::get` para capturar os valores passados para o parâmetro da requisição `addPedido/`

Assim:

```
Route::get('/addPedido', function() {
    $input = Input::only('numeroMesa', 'itens');

    var_dump($input['itens'], $input['numeroMesa']);
});
```

Não é necessário, portanto, a utilização do `json` para enviar os dados para o `Laravel`. Basta usar os parâmetros de url, para poder capturá-los numa requisição `GET`.

Comment: Corrigi. Não é necessário `{json}` nessa abordagem.

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Infelizmente quando eu faço essas alterações que você pediu, eu tenho um erro interno (500 Internal Server Error). E ainda ficaram ainda algumas dúvidas, será que você pode me ajudar?


1) Como 'itens' se trata de um array, ele pode ter vários elementos armazenados. Mesmo assim posso passá-lo normalmente em uma requisição get?  (por isso eu estava tentando utilizar um json)


2) Na rota, quando escrevo var_dump, como eu faço pra ver o resultado disso, já que não está sendo retornado para a view através do 'return'? 

De qualquer forma, muito obrigado pela resposta.

Comment: @GabrielAugusto pode sim. O `jQuery` converte automaticamente. Faça um teste (para você se sentir mais seguro). Faça isso e veja o que aparece no console: `console.log($.param(json))`.

Comment: Encontrei meu erro aqui, amigo, eu ainda estava passando $json na função da rota. Muito obrigado pela ajuda rápida e direta!

Comment: só mais uma pergunta: existe alguma forma de eu verificar qual é esse erro interno que acontece? Por exemplo, se eu fizer alguma bobeira na rota, utilizando PHP, e der um erro, é possível eu ver qual é esse erro?
obrigado!

Comment: Sim. Vá em `config/app.php` e configure a linha `"debug" => true`.

Comment: Essa pergunta aqui no SOPT seria importante.